# Showing the same photo for 2 modal buttons

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal, modalpopupextender

I want to display 2 photos on Text & Text 1 buttons. But both modal buttons shows the picture on the Text 1 / Showing the same photo for 2 modal buttons.

I tried the similar question answers on here and any of them didn't work. I tried removing the Text 01 modal, Then it worked. I tried some methods and it also didn't help me. I'm new at php sorry.

Here are the modals.

```
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#myImg3 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg3:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 100; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.modal-backdrop
{
    opacity:0 !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#"><text id="myBtn3">Photo</text></a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal3" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" id="img03">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal3");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn3");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
<!--Certificate End--></p>
 <html>
<!--Certificate Start-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 100; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.modal-backdrop
{
    opacity:0 !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#"><text id="myBtn">Photo 1</text></a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods_wide.jpg" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what you actually needed? you expect to show the  2 images in one click?

Comment: No i want to show 2 different images on Text modal and Text 1 modal

Comment: So, You can include the two images in same div?

Comment: I can't see any php here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a conflict with duplicated ids (both trigger buttons and modals had the same ID), if you want an element to do a different thing they need an unique ID.

```html
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#myImg3 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg3:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 100; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.modal-backdrop
{
    opacity:0 !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#"><text id="myBtn3">Photo</text></a>
<a href="#"><text id="myBtn">Photo 1</text></a>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal3" class="modal">
  <span class="close" id="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" id="img03">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close" id="close1">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods_wide.jpg" id="img01">
  <div id="caption2"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal3"); 
var modal2 = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn3");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementById("close");
var span2 = document.getElementById("close1");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

span2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  
  if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```